# JS PayPal REST Error: MALFORMED_REQUEST

Tags: javascript, paypal

I try to integrate PayPal API to my app. When I try to make call to API in my script I got an error:
Incoming JSON request does not map to API request. This is the full object of error:

> debug_id:"8280412cbada"
>   information_link:"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST"
>
> message:"Incoming JSON request does not map to API request"
>      name:"MALFORMED_REQUEST"

But when I try to make call via EasyRest with the same parameters all is working OK.

This is the code which I used to make call:

```
function payPalStep3(gAccessToken, gPrice, gCurrency, gOrderNumber){ return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

let newPayment = {
  intent: 'sale',
  redirect_urls: {
    return_url: 'http://localhost:3000/success.html', 
    cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3000/reject.html'
  },
  payer: {
    payment_method: 'paypal'
  },
  transactions: [{
    amount: {
      total: parseFloat(gPrice),
      currency: gCurrency
    }
  }]
}

let req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  let UrlReq = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment'; 
  req.open('POST', UrlReq, true); 
  req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
  req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+gAccessToken);
  req.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(req.readyState == 4){
    let shopUserResponse = req.response;
    shopUserResponse = JSON.parse(shopUserResponse);

      resolve(shopUserResponse); 
    }
    req.onerror = () => err(false);
  }
  req.send(newPayment) })}
```

Maybe somebody can help me, please.

Comment: I put the same parameters in my query in RESTEASY and it's working. I checked twice :) But when I used script I got an error. I think that the problem in my code. It's not problem in parameters.

Comment: Please use a debugger and provide the exact request payload (excluding the auth data of course).

Comment: jannis thank you for your reply. I used debugger and didn't find any bugs in the code. There is the object which I get from my function and later user it for call:

Comment: {
  "intent":"sale",
  "redirect_urls":{
   "return_url":"http://localhost:3000/success.html",
   "cancel_url":"http://localhost:3000/reject.html"
  },
  "payer":{
   "payment_method":"paypal"
  },
  "transactions":[
    {
    "amount":{
     "total":23,
     "currency":"EUR"
     }
    }
   ]
 }

Comment: And all is OK at this step. And I told already that I used this object in RestEasy and it's working.